# Ionic 6 React: Change IonItem lines color

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react, ionic6

[image]

I want to change the border bottom of this `IonItem`,

i tried adding a class called **border-light**

```
<IonItem
  lines="inset"
  color="primary"
  className="ion-align-items-center ion-margin-vertical border-light"
 >
```

And css

```
.border-light {
  --border-color: var(--ion-color-light);
}
```

Comment: `lines="none"` and then use class to add `border-bottom: 5px solid red`;

Comment: This trick works!

Answer (score -1):

Template:

```
<IonItem
  lines="none"
  color="primary"
  className="ion-align-items-center ion-margin-vertical border-light"
 >
```

CSS:

```
IonItem.border-light{
--border-color: var(--ion-color-light) !important; // to override primary class style
--border-style:inset;   
--border-width:2px;
border-top-style :none;
border-right-style :none;
border-left-style :none;
}
```

Comment: This does not work sir